# locate excludes hidden files?

Tags: filesystem, configuration

How to configure `locate` so that it indexes all files including hidden ones?
Or what does `locate` exclude in its search?

Comment: My 'locate' shows hidden files (like ~/.bashrc). ???

Comment: Interesting, I can also search for .bashrc. However, I have other hidden folders that don't get searched for some reason. I did sudo updatedb as well.

Comment: I also faced same problem but it got resolved just by the updatedb command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior does not explicitly exclude hidden folders. According to the [manual for updatedb.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man5/updatedb.conf.5.html), no paths are skipped except for those listed in `PRUNENAMES`, which is unset by default:

```
$ cat /etc/updatedb.conf
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media"
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre_lite tmpfs usbfs udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs ecryptfs fusesmb devtmpfs"
```

To verify this behavior, try:

```
$ sudo mkdir /.testfolder
$ sudo touch /.testfolder/.testfile
$ sudo updatedb -v | grep /\\.test
//.testfolder
/.testfolder/.testfile
$ locate test | grep /\\.test
/.testfolder
/.testfolder/.testfile
```

Comment: Oh, my /home/ is encrypted. See my follow-up question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20821/using-locate-on-an-encrypted-partition