# using locate on an encrypted partition

Tags: filesystem, encryption

I selected /home/ to be encrypted when I was installing Ubuntu. Now, is it possible to make `locate` work with an encrypted partition like this?

Comment: I have the same problem - locate will find files outside of my encrypted home partition but cannot see them inside it. (To be honest, I wish I'd never encrypted it when I installed Ubuntu in the first place, with all the problems I've had with it!)  Please can someone explain in clear steps what I need to do to be able to make locate be able to index data on an encrypted home partition.  I'm a relative newbie so it's not obvious what to do from reading the above:).

Comment: Your `/home` is a virtual file system (ecryptfs). It is "mounted" as an accessible partition when you log in. Check your /etc/updatedb.conf and a) remove ecryptfs from ignored file systems (PRUNEFS) b) change to PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="no"

Comment: After that you can run `sudo updatedb` to index new files.

Comment: keep in mind that the database locate uses lives in unencrypted space, possibly compromising your encryption by disclosing filenames

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I both "run locate (updatedb) when I'm logged in", as mentioned above, and I keep **my** part of the locate database under my encrypted $HOME.

```
export LOCATE_PATH="$HOME/var/mlocate.db"
```

and then I index the files in`$HOME` with

```
updatedb -l 0 -o $HOME/var/mlocate.db -U $HOME
```

Now I have a complete index of `$HOME` but the database isn't visible unless `$HOME` is mounted and decrypted.

Comment: That's a nice solution. How did you migrate your db there?

Comment: I didn't. I just generated a db for my (encrypted) home tree, with `updatedb -l 0 -o $HOME/var/mlocate.db $HOME`. `man locate` says it will search the default database (`/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`), **then** the list of databases in `$LOCATE_PATH`.

Comment: **Don't** "remove `ecryptfs` from the `PRUNEFS` definition in `/etc/updatedb.conf`. When you're logged in, `/home/$USER` is decrypted, but the encrypted files and filenames in `/home/$USER/.Private` should be ignored. When your `$HOME` is not mounted, others won't have access to the db or the (unencrypted) files of filenames.

Comment: `updatedb -l 0 -o $HOME/var/mlocate.db $HOME` there is missing `-U` it should be `updatedb -l 0 -o $HOME/var/mlocate.db -U $HOME`

Comment: My bad, @destin I've extended my method to index removeable media, too, using Steve Collyer's bash_path_funcs ( http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645 ). With the removeable medium mounted (as `/media/_name_`) I do `updatedb -l 0 -o ~/var/mlocate/_name_.db -U /media/_name_`  

In my `.bashrc`, I have

    `export LOCATE_PATH="$HOME/var/mlocate/mlocate.db`  

    `for i in $HOME/var/mlocate/*.db ; do`  

        `addpath -p LOCATE_PATH $i`  

    `done`  

    `uniqpath -p LOCATE_PATH`  
    
and `locate` can show me filenames even when the medium is *NOT* mounted.

Comment: What is the best place to add these lines to automate running the updatedb regularly when I'm logged in?

Comment: @Ossi-Viljakainen: 2nd questions belong in their own question, so later users can find it.

Comment: This works. However, how to inform mlocate to use the new mlocate.db database file? I now rely on the option -d i.e.: mlocate -d  ~/var/mlocate.db the_file_i_want.txt

Comment: @MartienLubberink 2nd questions belong in their own question, so later users can find it.

Comment: See also this addition to .bashrc: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428143/changing-the-default-database-for-locate-and-mlocate/428345#428345

Answer (score 3):

How about running updatedb when your file system is decrypted and try to match environment variables to read/write it?

After reading the man page, add two variables to your BASH RC file.

```
man locate
echo "export LOCATE_PATH=$HOME/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db:$LOCATE_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export DBPATH=$HOME/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db:$DBPATH" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Make the directory specified above and add $username to the mlocate group.

```
mkdir -p ~/var/lib/mlocate/
sudo usermod -a -G mlocate $username
```

Log out and in again to count your user in the mlocate group and get the new environment variables. Now when you run,

```
updatedb -o $LOCATE_PATH
```

are the decrypted files in a locate database now? Or, what did you do to make it work or better?

You may also want to add updatedb to user's crontab. First run:

```
crontab -e
```

And add the following line:

```
0 12 * * * updatedb -o $HOME/var/locate
```

Comment: See my comment to Martin. I'm trying to understand if there are any security considerations or proper configuration was just overlooked by Ubuntu.

Comment: Because of ecryptfs being listed in the PRUNEFS variable at /etc/updatedb.conf, you probably also need to use --prunefs "nfs" . This seems to be a good solution because it stores and updates the a per user index from the user profile.

Comment: @m33lky The issue is this: you have asked to encrypt your homedir, so nobody (not even `root`!) can read it without the password.  The smart solution is a per-user locate database.  The easy solution for a single-user machine is to remove `ecryptfs` and scan when you are logged in.  In the future, perhaps `locate` could aggregate results from the global DB and the current user's home DB.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really possible to update the database index without being logged in. You should log in and run the updatedb command.

Check your config in `/etc/updatedb.conf`. Remove `ecryptfs` from `PRUNEFS` and probably `/home/.ecryptfs` from `PRUNEPATHS`. Don't forget to run `sudo updatedb` after.

Comment: updatedb.conf prunes ecryptfs. Also, PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes". I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind such defaults as this is not user-friendly to have results from /home missing in your searches :)

Comment: I'm guessing the functionality for home is to have a per user indexer... but that's speculation.

Comment: Without encryption /home gets indexed, so I expect the same behavior...

Comment: Then figure out how to make a global index of an encrypted partition that doesn't count as a security breach. You're asking for the logically impossible.

Comment: You're making up an impossible problem. Encrypting the db would do just fine.

Comment: I was describing the situation from the user interface perspective.

Comment: If you encrypted the entire disk, this wouldn't be an issue, if you only had a home encryption then you now need to start indexing per user and using each individual encryption... in fact you might as well just stash the home index in the user's home folder.... all of which is major development and cost for something most users never see. Please report the bug against the locate database tools project.