# Locate does not locate files

Tags: 14.04, locate

I have not used locate for a while and today when I look for a file that I had put away for more than a year, locate does not pick it up. I ran find to get it.

It appears that none of the files in my home directory are in the index. Only files & folders from system directories like usr, var, are located.

I tried updatedb but no luck. Has my home directory somehow got excluded from the index?

Comment: Did you ran the updatedb command with sudo? If not, repeat it with sudo.

Comment: Yes, I did "sudo updatedb"

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Open the file `/etc/updatedb.conf` and check if the excluded path is listed in the `PRUNEPATHS` or the excluded path is using one of the filesystems enumerated in `PRUNEFS`.

If so, modify the conf file, and run again the `sudo updatedb` command.

(If you have encrypted your home directory while installing, then remove from the config the `encryptfs` entries.)

Comment: Yes, it is. Removed it and ran updatedb and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: If you have encrypted your home directory, consider  **not** removing `ecrypts` from the `PRUNEFS` list of file system types for security reasons. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/93477/633305) instead.