# Why doesn't 'locate' find files in '/run' directory?

Tags: locate

The command `sudo find / -name "php7.2-fpm.sock"` returns `/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock` but `sudo locate php7.2-fpm.sock` is empty.

PS: used `sudo  updatedb`  before.

Comment: The /run directory may be excluded from indexing. If so you can remove from excluded list.

Comment: +1 indeed, `/run` is typically mounted as type `tmpfs`, which is one of the default `PRUNEFS` types in `/etc/updatedb.conf`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix would you like to roll that up into an answer?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm on my phone for five more hours before I can answer. Go ahead and answer if you like. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by @WinEunuuchs2Unix (concept) and @steeldriver (technical details).

- **Concept**: `locate`  can exclude directory from its indexing process.
- **Detail**: there are a "`locate` configuration file", `/etc/updatedb.conf` ([**man page**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/updatedb.conf.5.html)) and you can declare many exclusion rules —  excluded paths, files or directories will be not scanned by `updatedb`. Each rule is declared by a variable:

  - `PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS`: use "YES" to exclude mounted direcories — so bind mounts are not scanned.
  - `PRUNENAMES`: list of excluded *directory names*.
  - `PRUNEPATHS`: list  of  excluded *path  names*  of  directories.
  - `PRUNEFS`: used when `PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS` is flagged ("0" or "NO"), it is a list of *file system  types*, like [old `/etc/mtab` system  types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/514095/130402) to be excluded.

---

### `/etc/updatedb.conf` DUMP

The problem described in the question occurred in the context of:

```
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /var/lib/os-prober /var/lib/ceph /home/.ecryptfs /var/lib/schroot"
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs devtmpfs fuse.mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre tmpfs usbfs udf fus
e.glusterfs fuse.sshfs curlftpfs ceph fuse.ceph fuse.rozofs ecryptfs fusesmb"
```

So, `PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"` excluded `/run` from `updatedb` indexation.

---

Similar questions:

- https://serverfault.com/q/454051/355484
- https://askubuntu.com/a/93477/439867
- ...

Comment: Thanks for answering for me. Now I can go do some Python coding :). The only thing different I would have done in my answer is run `sudo time updatedb`, listed size of database, set `PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="no"`, rerun `updatedb` with new time report and database size.